# Share results of asynchronous call between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller

I have a `RootVC` with container views for `MapVC` and `ListVC`. 
Since I need to make an API call and share the results amongst both `MapVC` and `ListVC`, I created a `RootVCDelegate`.

```
protocol RootVCDelegate {
    func fetch(results: [Object]) -> Void
}
```

in `prepare(for UIStoryboardSegue:)` I respectively set `RootVCDelegate` property to `MapVC` or `ListVC` depending on the identifier. I know this won't work, because delegate property can only have one value.

Delegation pattern won't work here, so how can I share results of async call between these view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make `RootVCDelegate` an array of delegates and then when you want to perform on the delegates do `delegats.forEach { ..... }` and when assigning a delegate just append the delegate to `delegates`

Example:

```
// Delegate Protocol
protocol RootVCDelegate {
    fetch(results: [Objects]) //returning Void does nothing so no need to write it
}

// RootVC
class RootVC {
    delegates: [RootVCDelegate]

    prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let destination = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController).rootViewController ?? segue.destination  // how I like to handle things if there's a possibility of a UINavigationController housing my UIViewController
        switch destination {
        case _ as MapVC: delegates.append(destination)
        case _ as ListVC: delegates.append(destination)
        default: return
        }
    }
}
```

This may be what you're asking for?

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would do the trick. However, I ended up using the NotificationCenter.

Comment: Nice, that was going to be my next suggestion, but didn't know how familiar you would be with it. Wanted to give something you knew! NotificationCenter is a good solution though :)